# Arbitrary infinite sequence of individuals correlating - Rogers, Mathematical logic and formalized theories.

Tags: sequences-and-series, logic, predicate-logic

In Robert Roger's 'Mathematical logic and formalized theories', there's the following paragraph:

> We need next the concept of an arbitrary infinite sequence of
>   individuals within D . The variables of F1 are arranged in an infinite
>   sequence. Thus, each infinite sequence of individuais within D
>   correlates with each of the variables of F1 some individual within
>   D . Thus, in particular, given any formula A and infinite sequence of individuais S = (b1, b2, ...), each of the free variables within A
>   has some individual within D correlated with it by S.

I'd like to understand what he means by an infinite sequence of individuals **correlating** other things. How can sequences of individuals (b1, b2...) correlate anything whatsoever? Isn't correlating something that only relations can do? I don't understand.

Thank you.

Comment: Consider a function $s : \text {Var} \to D$ where $\text {Var}$ is the set of individual variables $x_i$. Thus, $s(x_i)= b_i \in D$.

Comment: To summarize Mauro's comments: This is basically just a rather technical way of talking about *variable assignments* - the sequence S yields a way to interpret a formula with free variables x_1, x_2, ..., x_n as talking about specific elements of D.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I think you should post your second comment (maybe elaborated on) as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:

- Robert  Rogers, [Mathematical Logic and Formalized Theories: A Survey of Basic Concepts and Results](https://books.google.it/books?id=fJziBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA36) (1971), page 36:

We may consider a function $s : \text {Var} \to D$, where $\text {Var}$ is the set of individual variables $\{ x_i \}$, as a way to correlate to each variable $x_i$ an element $b_i$ of the domain $D$, i.e. $s(x_i)=b_i$.

In this way, we may "give meaning" to a formula $A$ with free variables.

Consider for example the language for *arithmetic* and the set $\mathbb N$ of *natural* numbers.

Consider the function $s$ that correlates $x_1$ with the number $0$, $x_2$ with $1$ and so on: $s(x_{n+1})=n \in \mathbb N$.

Consider now as $A$ the formula $(x_2=1)$, with $x_2$ free.

We have that, with the interpretation above and with the "variable assignment" function $s$, the formula $A$ is satisfied; in symbols:

> $\mathbb N, s \vDash (x_2=1)$,

exactly because $s$ assigns to $x_2$ the "meaning" $1$ and $1=1$ is *true* in $\mathbb N$.

Things are different with a different function $s'$ such that e.g. $s'(x_2)=0$. In this case: $\mathbb N, s' \nvDash (x_2=1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's much clearer now that you explained it using variable assignments. Thank you @Noah Schweber for your comment as well!